# Are there any provable real-world languages? (scala?)

Tags: java, scala, testing, functional-programming, formal-verification

I was taught about [formal systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) at university, but I was disappointed how they didn't seem to be used in the real word.

I like the idea of being able to know that some code (object, function, whatever) works, not by testing, but by **proof**.

I'm sure we're all familiar with the parallels that don't exist between physical engineering and software engineering (steel behaves predictably, software can do anything - who knows!), and I would love to know if there are any languages that can be use in the real word (is asking for a web framework too much to ask?)

I've heard interesting things about the testability of functional languages like scala.

As software **engineers** what options do we have?

Comment: Any Turing complete language suffers the problem that this, at least in the general case, is undecidable. (this is commonly known as the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

Comment: Software engineering is an oxymoron. It isn't engineering in the accepted sense of the word.  Further, software isn't hardware.  When a bolt falls out of a bridge, the bridge does not fall. A single error in software can stop the entire program.  We can adopt techniques to make things better, but it will never be "engineering."  It will be a long time before we see a 'provably correct' piece of non-trivial software. Consider we can't even get the *requirements* document right if 3 people are involved...

Comment: @Tony Wikipedia defines engineering as the discipline and art of acquiring and applying scientific, mathematical, and practical knowledge to design and build systems and processes that safely realize solutions to the needs of society. A single error should no more bring down well-engineered software than a single missing bolt would bring down a well-engineered bridge under the operating conditions for which they were designed. As with structural engineering, the best we can do is prove that our software works under reasonably expected conditions by using reviews, tests, and yes, formal proofs.

Comment: @Mark E, the fact that a language is Turing complete does **not** imply that you can't reason about the behavior of programs written in this language and prove it correct. What's true though, is that there can't be a fully automated "push-button" technique for this.

Comment: @aioobe: I wrote what I wrote pretty carefully: it can't be done in the *general* case. You can certainly reason about the correctness of programs, and for subsets of programs, you can prove they're correct, but there is no single Turing-complete language that is entirely provable, IIRC.

Comment: First of all, when you say that a language is "provable", I suppose you mean "programs written in the language can be proven correct". A program written in *any* language can be proven to be correct (provided you have a well defined semantics/spec). I suspect what you're *trying* to say is the following: A program written in a turing complete language can't *automatically* be proven correct given for instance the specification "this program terminates". However, no-one has claimed that formal methods is only to be applied automatically. Much of it is a manual process, just like programming is.

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Comment: @MarkE -- the error here is that you're not trying to prove a property of any arbitrary program, you're trying to prove that a particular specific program satisfies a particular specific specification.  So, for example, if you have a specification "print the number five", it's straightforward to prove that "prinln(5)" does that, with appropriate base axioms.

Comment: @aioobe:  You seem to be saying that manual proof techniques are in some sense more powerful than automatic proof techniques.  Doesn't this get into trouble with the Church-Turing thesis?  Either this involves a leap of intuition that transcends normal calculation, and apparently a frequently repeatable one, or it is automatable.  Similarly, as a human, I can only distinguish a finite and knowable alphabet of symbols, and it's reasonable to assume I can't make a proof over, say, a million symbols long.  If proof validity is defined, a computer can find any proof I can.

Comment: *manual proof techniques are in some sense more powerful than automatic proof techniques*, well in a practical setting I'd suppose that a manual proof technique sometimes has advantages over an automated one. Wouldn't you agree? But sure, if all proofs are enumerable and validity is decidable, an automated proof technique is in theory just as powerful.

Comment: There are provers that can prove some theorems about some programs written in a suitable languages. A prover that can prove any theorem for any program in a given Turing complete language can not exist (Rice's Theorem). A good compromise seem to be interactive theorem provers. And yes, proving things is a lot easier if you do not have side-effects.

Comment: Btw, I do not think that traditional engineering disciplines have inherently better material. In their models, they calculate things to work out, but if mistakes happen during manufacturing, the model is no longer appropriate. I guess it is their larger fault tolerance that makes the difference.

Comment: You might be interested in this book: [Adam Chlipala: Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/). To quote:
>  The focus is on building programs with proofs of correctness, using dependent types and scripted proof automation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, there are languages designed for writing provably correct software. Some are even used in industry. [Spark Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARK_%28programming_language%29) is probably the most prominent example. I've talked to a few people at Praxis Critical Systems Limited who used it for code running on Boings (for engine monitoring) and it seems quite nice. (Here is a great [summary / description of the language](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall01/G22.3033-007/spintro.ppt).) This language and accompanying proof system uses the second technique described below. It doesn't even support dynamic memory allocation!

---

My impression and experience is that there are two techniques for writing correct software:

- Technique 1: Write the software in a language you're comfortable with (C, C++ or Java for instance). Take a formal specification of such language, and prove your program correct.

  If your ambition is to be 100% correct (which is most often a requirement in automobile / aerospace industry) you'd be spending little time programming, and more time proving.
- Technique 2: Write the software in a slightly more awkward language (some subset of Ada or tweaked version of OCaml for instance) and write the correctness proof along the way. Here programming and proving goes hand in hand. Programming in Coq even equates them completely! (See the [Curry-Howard correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence))

  In these scenarios you'll always end up with a correct program. (A bug will be guaranteed to be rooted in the specification.) You'll be likely to spend more time on programming but on the other hand you're proving it correct along the way.

Note that both approaches hinges on the fact you have a formal specification at hand (how else would you tell what is correct / incorrect behavior), and a formally defined semantics of the language (how else would you be able to tell what the actual behavior of your program is).

Here are a few more examples of formal approaches. If it's "real-world" or not, depends on who you ask :-)

- The Coq Theorem Prover: [Programming with Coq](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/Tsinghua/C1.pdf) (technique 2)
- [ESC/Java](http://secure.ucd.ie/products/opensource/ESCJava2/) (technique 1, neither sound nor complete though)
- [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) (technique 1, neither sound nor complete though)
- [Why / Krakatoa](http://krakatoa.lri.fr/) (technique 2, based on Java)

I know of only one "provably correct" **web-application language**: [UR](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/). A Ur-program that "goes through the compiler" is guaranteed not to:

- Suffer from any kinds of code-injection attacks
- Return invalid HTML
- Contain dead intra-application links
- Have mismatches between HTML forms and the fields expected by their handlers
- Include client-side code that makes incorrect assumptions about the "AJAX"-style services that the remote web server provides
- Attempt invalid SQL queries
- Use improper marshaling or unmarshaling in communication with SQL databases or between browsers and web servers

Comment: As an example of using technique 2 for a real world engineering problem, Coq was used to prove the correctness of the JavaCard security features

Comment: Right, I've read one of the papers on that project. Quite impressive.

Comment: Spark looks comprehensive, but can I build web apps in it? I'm reluctant to make my UI in anything else.

Comment: In theory: I guess so. In practice: I guess not. :-) Seriously though, it wouldn't be practical at all. For security critical web-pages, I'd recommend UR as mentioned in my answer. Still, I doubt you'll find it compelling for the everyday web-programming. Since you seem to be into Scala, how about giving the [Lift Framework](http://liftweb.net/) a go?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Lift. I've taken a look at that, however I think a real barrier to scala's provability is in it's lack of strict FP. The language is too expressive. This, of course, makes it better for general purpose work..

Comment: I think Haskell is the way forward, as it is strict FP and has a few web frameworks (though all low-level). I'll continue my research into modelchecking, verification and proving Haskell!

Comment: Sure. It's a popular language so it has a large user base and good community as well.

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Comment: Here is a real-world example with a positive cost benefit analysis (I think it would be helpful to include it in your answer as it is still a top result on google) https://blog.adacore.com/nvidia-security-team-what-if-we-just-stopped-using-c

Answer (score 24):

In order to answer this question, you really need to define what you mean by "provable".  As Ricky pointed out, any language with a type system is a language with a built-in proof system which runs every time you compile your program.  These proof systems are almost always sadly impotent — answering questions like `String` vs `Int` and avoiding questions like "is the list sorted?" — but they are proof systems none-the-less.

Unfortunately, the more sophisticated your proof goals, the harder it is to work with a system which can check your proofs.  This escalates pretty quickly into undecidability when you consider the sheer size of the class of problems which are undecidable on Turing Machines.  Sure, you can theoretically do basic things like proving the correctness of your sorting algorithm, but anything more than that is going to be treading on very thin ice.

Even to prove something simple like the correctness of a sorting algorithm requires a comparatively sophisticated proof system.  (note: since we have already established that type systems are a proof system built into the language, I'm going to talk about things in terms of type theory, rather than waving my hands still more vigorously)  I'm fairly certain that a full correctness proof on list sorting would require some form of dependent types, otherwise you have no way of referencing relative values at the type level.  This immediately starts breaking into realms of type theory which have been shown to be undecidable.  So, while you may be able to prove correctness on your list sorting algorithm, the only way to do it would be to use a system which will also allow you to express proofs which it cannot verify.  Personally, I find this very disconcerting.

There is also the ease-of-use aspect which I alluded to earlier.  The more sophisticated your type system, the less pleasant it is to use.  That's not a hard and fast rule, but I think it holds true for the most part.  And as with any formal system, you will often find that expressing the proof is more work (and more error prone) than creating the implementation in the first place.

With all that out of the way, it's worth noting that Scala's type system (like Haskell's) is Turing Complete, which means that you can *theoretically* use it to prove any decidable property about your code, provided that you have written your code in such a way that it is amenable to such proofs.  Haskell is almost certainly a better language for this than Java (since type-level programming in Haskell is similar to Prolog, while type-level programming in Scala is more similar to SML).  I don't advise that you use Scala's or Haskell's type systems in this way (formal proofs of algorithmic correctness), but the option is theoretically available.

Altogether, I think the reason you haven't seen formal systems in the "real world" stems from the fact that formal proof systems have yielded to the merciless tyranny of pragmatism.  As I mentioned, there's so much effort involved in crafting your correctness proofs that it's almost never worthwhile.  The industry decided a long time ago that it was easier to create ad hoc tests than it was to go through any sort of analytical formal reasoning process.

Comment: I thought Turing languages were difficult or impossible to prove, unlike λ-calculus-based languages?

Comment: "So, while you may be able to prove correctness on your list sorting algorithm, the only way to do it would be to use a system which will also allow you to express proofs which it cannot verify." I don't get this. Surly all sane proof systems must be able to tell whether or not a proof is valid or not?

Comment: What's hard about proofing that a list is sorted?

Comment: @aioobe: A proofer for proofing such things is most likely Turing-complete itself, that means that you can input code into the proofer which makes it run in a loop or something like that.

Comment: @soc, to prove that a list is sorted? Thats obviously trivial. To prove that a sorting algorithm sorts a list is different. Very very very different. @soc, uhm, I'm not sure I follow you. (I do know about the halting problem, but I don't really see the relation here.)

Comment: I'm still in the process of learning Coq and the theory behind it, but AFAIK, you can't construct unverifiable proofs (unless you state it as an axiom, essentially saying "I don't have a proof"). What you can't do in Coq is to prove the consistency of the logic system itself (you'll smack into Gödel's incompleteness)

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Comment: @GClaramunt: Coq is contrived in such a way that unverifiable proofs aren't an issue.  However, that is very different from having your proof system built into the language itself (as a type system).  I don't have a proof for this, but my intuition/experience is that such a type system would quickly become Turing Complete, immediately implying the existence of expressible proofs which cannot be verified in finite time (undecidability).

Comment: @Daniel As my (limited) understanding goes, the calculus of (inductive) constructions is a typed lambda calculus, Coq can be seen as syntactic sugar over it, and is not Turing complete. In theory it should be possible (but really cumbersome) to just use it as the type system... (again, take it with a grain of salt, my understanding is pretty limited)

Comment: Scala's type system is turing complete - http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/scala-type-level-encoding-of-the-ski-calculus/

Answer (score 10):

You're asking a question a lot of us have asked over the years.  I don't know that I have a good answer, but here are some pieces:

- There are well-understood languages with the possibility of being proven in use today; Lisp via ACL2 is one, and of course Scheme has a well-understood formal definition as well.
- a number of systems have tried to use pure functional languages, or nearly pure ones, like Haskell.  There's a fair bit of formal methods work in Haskell.
- Going back 20+ years, there was a short-lived thing for using hand-proof of a formal language which was then rigorously translated into a compiled language.  Some examples were IBM's Software Cleanroom, ACL, Gypsy, and Rose out of Computational Logic, John McHugh's and my work on trustworthy compilation of C, and my own work on hand-proof for C systems programming.  These all got some attention, but none of them made it much into practice.

An interesting question to ask, I think, is what would sufficient conditions be to get formal approaches into practice?  I'd love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: Could you elaborate about the formal methods of haskell?

Comment: @Oatman, I can't really in any detail; I just know I spent some time on a Navy project several years ago and some of the guys down the hall were using Haskell for specification and proof.  I'd try googling "haskell specification security" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I'll take a look. Haskell seems a mature FP language, I'll concentrate my research there.

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Comment: Here is a real world example of nvidia using it and the retrospective cost benefit analysis was favorable. https://blog.adacore.com/nvidia-security-team-what-if-we-just-stopped-using-c

Comment: @S.Melted thanks for that. I did soem basic studies in grad school that suggested cost of maintenance was reduced by 2-3 orders of magnitude in telephony code, but no one was interested.

Answer (score 9):

Typed languages prove the absence of certain categories of fault.  The more advanced the type system, the more faults they can prove the absence of.

For proof that a whole program works, yes, you're stepping outside the boundaries of ordinary languages, where mathematics and programming meet each other, shake hands and then proceed to talk using Greek symbols about how programmers can't handle Greek symbols.  That's about the Σ of it anyway.

Comment: You have a nice explanation, but have you read some Spark code? You write quite readable (and provable correct) programs (and it's in pure ascii ;)

Comment: Here's another example that I like to use, this time with C functions (the annotation language has much in common with SPARK, and in the same way that if you can learn Ada you can learn SPARK, if you can learn C you can learn this specification language): http://www.first.fraunhofer.de/owx_download/acsl-by-example-5_1_0.pdf

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Answer (score 4):

real world uses of such provable languages would be incredibly difficult to write and understand afterwoods.
the business world needs working software, fast.

"provable" languages just dont scale for writing/reading a large project's code base and only seem to work in small and isolated use cases.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think we are moving towards provable software, and I'm sure they are not bound to always be slow to develop

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Omega](http://code.google.com/p/omega/).

This [introduction](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/papers/SumSchNotes.ps) contains a relatively painless implementation of AVL trees with included correctness proof.

Comment: Ha - Omega! Is that a tip of the hat the the Halting Problem? I'll check it out.

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Answer (score 4):

I'm involved in two provable languages. The first is the language supported by Perfect Developer, a system for specifying sotfware, refining it and generating code. It's been used for some large systems, including PD itself, and it's taught in a number of universities. The second provable language I'm involved with is a provable subset of MISRA-C, see [C/C++ Verification Blog](http://critical.eschertech.com) for more.

Comment: Thanks David, C seems a step backwards for me, though I see the utility of it from a low-level safety-critical systems perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can investigate *purely functional languages* like Haskell, which are used when one of your requirements is *provability*.

[This](http://ctocorner.com/fsharp/book/ch1.aspx) is a fun read if you're interested about functional programming languages and pure functional programming languages.

Comment: I agree. Pure functional programming is a very good compromise between provability and "normal" programming, since pure functions are much easier to test, and this is usually enough.

Comment: @Olle, "easier to test"? I'm afraid that you've misunderstood what formal methods are all about...

Comment: @aioobe, Agreed, it's the mathematical certainty that your program works as you want, not that it passes some tests with no idea about their coverage. This is what I'm searching for.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe my search will be in vain, and FP will provide easier testing that I will have to accept for now.

Comment: @aioobe Sorry, the text was not very clear. When I say that FP is easier to test, I mean easier than imperative programs. Imperative code can be very hard to test.

Comment: @Olle, still though, as soon as you're talking about testing, you're talking about the opposite of formal methods.

Comment: Sounds like FP is the way to go for now! - I agree that formal methods are more satisfactory, but we have to be pragmatic too, right?

Comment: @Oatman, sure. It depends on what business you're into though. If human lives depend on your code, I bet you want to go with formal methods ;)

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Answer (score 3):

Scala is meant to be "real world", so no effort has been made to make it provable. What you can do in Scala is to produce functional code. Functional code is much easier to test, which is IMHO a good compromise between "real world" and provability.

EDIT =====
Removed my incorrect ideas about ML being "provable".

Comment: SML does have a fully-realized formal definition (one of the few non-trivial languages which does), but that doesn't mean that it's "provable" in the sense asked by the original question.  Many things about the *type system* are provable, but programs themselves remain comparatively opaque.

Comment: Quite possible, Olle, I think I may have to settle for a good FP languages for now!

Comment: I've asked another SO question based on the results of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077970/can-haskell-functions-be-proved-model-checked-verified-with-correctness-propertie

Comment: I think Scala actually is provable (using itself, that is) — there's an example on SO on how to prove the associativity of integer addition using pure Scala; it's awkward but possible.

Answer (score 3):

My (controversial) definition of "real-world" in the context of provably-correct code is:

- It must involve some degree of **automation**, otherwise you're going to spend far too much time proving and dealing with messy little details, and it's going to be totally impractical (except maybe for spacecraft control software and that sort of thing, for which you might actually want to spend megabucks on meticulous checks).
- It must support some degree of **functional programming**, which helps you write code that is very modular, reusable and easier to reason about. Obviously functional programming isn't needed for writing or proving Hello World, or a variety of simple programs, but at a certain point, functional programming does become very useful.
- While you don't necessarily have to be able to write your code in a mainstream programming language, as an alternative, you should at least be able to machine-translate your code into reasonably efficient code written in a mainstream programming language, in a reliable way.

The above are relatively more universal requirements. Others, such as the ability to model imperative code, or the ability to prove higher-order functions correct, may be important or essential for some tasks, but not all.

In view of these points, many of the tools listed in [this blog post of mine](http://www.greenrd.org/2012/06/comparison-of-functional-program-verifiers/) may be useful - although they are nearly all either new and experimental, or unfamiliar to the vast majority of industry programmers. There are some very mature tools covered there though.

Comment: I like your definitions, thanks for your blog post, it's very useful reading!

Answer (score 2):

How about [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org) and [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php)? Real world enough?

As a good real life example, there's a project that aims to provide a verified HTTP REST library written in Agda, called Lemmachine: https://github.com/larrytheliquid/Lemmachine